# Running .ktr created in windows on centos 6.5 server

Tags: linux, centos, pentaho, kettle

Folks,

I trust all is well.

We have .ktr files that are created in widows 7 that we need to run on a centos 6.5 server using pan.

I am trying to run the following command the server:

[root@BTNYSLDVD01 data-integration]# /home/pentaho/data-integration/pan.sh /file=/home/pentaho/data-integration/file.ktr

However I am getting the following error:

2015/10/07 13:03:28 - File Output.0 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The file.ktr file was created and runs properly without errors on a widows 7 computer.  The only modification I made was that I altered the `<server></server>` tag from `<server>ip address</server> to <server>localhost</server>`

I know that the password is correct because I am able to connect to the database from console.

We cannot create the .ktr files on the centos server since we do not have the desktop installed.

My question is "Is there snything special we need to do when running a .ktr file that was created in windows 7 on a centos 6.5 server"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Andy

Comment: Are u sure that there is role "root" in database? Are u sure "root" role if exists, has rights to connect to database on localhost?

Comment: Dear Simar thank you so much for getting back to me I am able to connect as root if I run mysql -h localhost -u root -p do I know the credentials are correct

Comment: Well u can configure transformation to use jndi. In this case all connection properties will be in jdbc.properties file which is located in KETTLE_HOME/simple-jndi directory in open format.

Answer (score 0):

First run this

```
cd data-integration
chmod +x *.sh
```

It will make the shell scripts executable.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it's hard  to know what is wrong.
I guess that you may have a problem of access via ssh : maybe you should have a key (e.g. generated via ssh-keygen) for the user root?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I believe the issue has to do with the password obfuscation not working properly on the centos server since the .ktr file was created in windows. Is there any way to make the password field un-encrypted in the .ktr file? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It gets pretty interesting. I find out on page
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

*"A Unix socket file is used if you do not specify a host name or if you specify the special host name **localhost**."*

Unix socket pretty special feature not available on Windows, but Kettle is written on Java which suppose to work on different OS, and can't use Unix socket since it's plafrorm specific. It has to use tcp/ip connection.

Against it,  ***mysql*** command is platform specific and able to utilize power of Unix socket, since it native tool.

Just try to put 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the issue. The issue was that mysql did not allow access from 127.0.0.1. We deployed pentaho on another server and were able to get the file to work. Thanks Simar for all your help.